# C++ Нужно добавить елемент массива на его начале, 0 елемент

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Нужно добавить один елемент в динамическом массиве на его начале, то есть добавить новый елемент с начала. В мною написанной функции первый елемент добавляется, но следующие два заполняються мусором, а должны сохранится как были. Помогите решить ету проблему...

```
void PushOnFirstPlace(int *&arr, int Size) {

    int FirstElement = 0;

    cout << "\n\tEnter the new element for the first place: ";

    cin >> FirstElement;

    int *TmpArr = new int[Size + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
        TmpArr[0] = FirstElement;
    }
    TmpArr[0] = FirstElement;

    delete[]arr;

    arr = TmpArr;

    PrintArray(arr, Size + 1);
}
```

Comment: Забыли массив скопировать, а первый эллемент кучу раз перезаписали. `for (i = 0; i < Size; ++i) {TmpArr[i+1] = arr[i];}` `TmpArr[0] = FirstElement;`

Comment: вы size раз инициализируете  TmpArr[0]  одним и тем же значением, а остальные элементы остаются неинициализированным,  плюс делается это не так, как вы пытаетесь

Comment: @Wootiae спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

```
void PushOnFirstPlace(int *&arr, int Size) {

    int FirstElement = 0;

    cout << "\n\tEnter the new element for the first place: ";

    cin >> FirstElement;

    int *TmpArr = new int[Size + 1];

    TmpArr[0] = FirstElement;

    for (int i = 1; i < Size; i++)
    {
        TmpArr[i] = arr[i-1];
    }

    delete[]arr;

    arr = TmpArr;

    PrintArray(arr, Size + 1);
}
```

наверное так